# How to fix Parsing error: Unexpected token?

Tags: css, reactjs

**I am trying to change my text color but I keep on getting Parsing error: Unexpected token as an error but don't know why can someone point out where my error is and how I would be able to fix that?**

**Code is below**

```
import React from 'react';
import react, { Component } from 'react'
import { Plateform, StyleSheet, view,text } from 'react-native';


**Here is where I am trying to change the text color everything seems to be in place but I keep on getting that unexpected token error?**

function Header() {
  return (
    <View style={style}>
    <Text style={[styles.setFontSize.setColorRed]} React Native Font example </Text>
      <header className="header">
        <div className="col1">
        </div>
        <div className="col2">
        <div className="menu">
        <h3>About</h3>
        <h3>Cars</h3>
        <h3>Contact</h3>
        <h3>Search</h3>
      </div>
      </div>
      </header>




  );
}

export default Header extends Component;
```

**This is the error I get?**

> ```
> ./src/components/header.js
>   Line 10:78:  Parsing error: Unexpected token
>
>      return (
>        <View style={style}>
>     <Text style={[styles.setFontSize.setColorRed]} React Native Font example </Text>
>                                                                                    ^
>          <header className="header">
>           <div className="col1">
>            </div
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should close your Text tag

```
<Text style={[styles.setFontSize.setColorRed]}> React Native Font example </Text>
                                              ^
```

And you haven't `</View>` tag

Watch some docs with examples from [reactnative.dev](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text) (that's a link to the Text component)